# Вывод image в laravel

Tags: laravel

У меня картинки хранятся в папке, `/storage/app/logo/`, в настройках я сделал -

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/logo'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

и выполнил `php artisan storage:link`, но если я пытаюсь подключить картинку /storage/app/logo/картинка, то не выходит. Что не так?

Answer (score 0):

не стоит вносить путаницу и переопределять диск public. Если необходимо - просто добавьте кастомный диск.

1 верните настройки в первоначальный вид:

```
    ...
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
    ...
```

2 в *.blade.php выведите изображение (при условии, что путь к изображению '/storage/app/public/logo/image.png'):

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage') . '/logo/image.png' }}" alt="image.png">
```

3 если еще не публиковали символическую ссылку - сделайте это в терминале:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

UPD: покажите вывод исходного кода сформированной страницы (конкретно - тег img).

Comment: Всё сделал как сказали, только картинка не image.png, а 1.jpg. Тег  -  <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/logo/1.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-thumbnail">  сама картинка не подключилась.

Comment: откройте в браузере страницу по адресу "127.0.0.1:8000/storage/logo/1.jpg",

Comment: если выдаст 404, то проверяйте наличие ссылки в public - она должна иметь вид lrwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    44 Aug 21 23:05 storage -> /full/path/to/project/storage/app/public

Comment: и проверьте права на ссылку.

Comment: А как посмотреть вид ссылки? У меня просто папка storage(ярлык) появился в папке public, а в ней - пусто.

Comment: Я понял))) путь к изображению должен быть следующий: /storage/app/public/logo/1.jpg! Я забыл про 'public'! Поправил ответ.

Comment: у меня папка logo на одном уровне с папкой public, может мне надо драйвер под неё отдельный сделать?

Comment: просто переместите её в директорию public. Не вижу смысла делать отдельный драйвер. Я бы её еще и в img положил бы.

Comment: мне надо именно, что бы была в отдельной директории, не public, а logo. Для этого нужно драйвер делать?

Comment: Если надо - то делайте, но созданная ранее ссылка на 'storage/app/public' не поможет разглядеть директорию 'storage/app/logo'. Необходимо будет вручную создать еще одну ссылку, и я не знаю, насколько это корректно. Вернее насколько это некорректно.